# how to view std:unordered_map member in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, unordered-map

When trying to access a member of std::unordered_map using [], I get an error:

> Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.

There is a nice [gdb-stl-views](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html#STLDEREF), except it does not support unordered_map.

Is there a similarly nice way to retrieve by key a member of unordered_map?

Comment: Indeed calling operator[] from gdb seems hard, but at least printing the whole map looks nice: `$1 = std::unordered_map with 2 elements = {[12] = 24, [3] = 6}`.

Comment: I did notice 'set print pretty on' in fact print the whole map with the key in [], which makes me think there's probably a nice way to retrieve a member by key. Printing the whole map is not really useful when dealing with very large map.

Comment: I believe you should report this to the bugzilla of either gcc or gdb.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are capable of viewing the member of `std::unordered_map` with an additional trivial step:

This is my test code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string make_key(const char *input) { return input; }// The additional function to make sure you could construct the key of your map in gdb from primitive type

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map = {
                {"bar", 100}
             };

        std::cout << map.at("bar");
}
```

And I am using `gdb 11.2` in `Archlinux`:

```sh
g++ -std=gnu++11 -O0 -g unordered_map_test.cpp -o unordered_map_test

gdb unordered_map_test
(gdb) p map
$1 = std::unordered_map with 1 element = {["bar"] = 100} 

// Perhaps it's useless to print all key-value pairs in map if you have a large map.

// Then you could print value of specific key

(gdb) p map.at(make_key("bar"))
$2 = (std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::hash<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> > >::mapped_type &) @0x55555556eed8: 100 // 100 is the value of `bar`

// If you think it's annoying that there is too much type information above, you could just print the value after you know the address of value.

(gdb) p *0x55555556eed8
$3 = 100
```